# Incorrect AngularJS email validation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm using AngularJS email validation as per `http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D`

I recently updated to 1.2.14 from 1.1.5, and there's definitely been a change in how email validation is handled.  In 1.2.14, `me@example` is valid, whereas in 1.1.5 it is not.

Is this change intentional?  Is there a way to get the old validation behavior without writing custom validation directives?

Comment: I see the validation works as same in 1.1.* and 1.2.*
You should put some code here for better analysis.

Comment: It doesn't work the same.  Try the demos on the angular docs and you'll see. `me@example` validates for 1.2.14 and doesn't for 1.1.5

Answer (score 1):

yes this is intentional. me@exanple is technically a valid email. You can add another regex filter that enforces a TLD if you want instead.